# Content is still attached to left edge in one column (responsive)

Tags: html, css

I've a problem with this:
[RWD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wnBy.png)

I'm trying to center these elements in one column (<960px) but I couldn't. I'm trying to use margin: 0 auto; but it still not working.

Comment: Add your code so we can understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
<div class = "container">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text1">Text1</label>
            <input type="text" id = "text1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text2">Text 2</label>
            <input type="email" id = "text2">
        </div>
    </form>
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.form-group{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
 }
 img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.col-one-third, .col-half {
width: 100%;
float: none;
```

}

```
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
.col-one-third {
    width: 33.3333%;
    float: left;


}

.col-half {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

}

For these elements on picture I set class="col-half"

Answer (score 0):

Without more context I, this generally works for centering:

```
.centered-item {
 float: none;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 display:block;  
}
```